# Is it possible to merge checked out files from one view in another

Tags: clearcase

I have a view in which I have checked-out 9 files , another team member wants to merge my changes in his activity but **I do not wish to check in the files**.

Is there a way to merge files without check in or some other alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `cleartool diff`, in order to generate **patches**, that you can then compressed and mail in an archive (.zip), for the other developer to apply.

See [`cleartool diff`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm).

That would be something like:

```
cleartool lsco -all -s -cview | xargs cleartool diff -diff_format -pred
```

> The `-diff_format` option causes both the headers and differences to be reported in the style of the UNIX and Linux diff utility, writing a list of the changes necessary to convert the first file being compared into the second file, as follows:
>
> - The first number (or range of numbers in the form n,n) indicates line numbers in the first file being compared.
> - The second value is one of the following: a d c. These indicate whether lines are to be added, deleted, or changed.
> - The second number (or range of numbers) indicates line numbers in the second file being compared.

Comment: hi @VonC I appreciate your inputs but the o/p of the above command is not very helpful would have to do the same tedious work of copy paste which i really want to avoid.

Comment: @yanivx no copy involved: script only: this must be fully automated. Those are classic unx diff that you can apply by script.

Comment: I am getting the following errors. I may be dumb enough to make this silly mistakes :(



cleartool lsco -all -s -cview | xargs cleartool diff -diff_format -pred
cleartool: Error: All contributors must be of the same file type.
cleartool: Error: "/vob/xxx/xxx/." is a directory but "/vob/xxxx/xxxx.xml" is not.